# Select elements accepting text input or displaying only text

Tags: css

How to select elements that can accept text as an input as well as elements that support only text display?

Comment: if you manage to answer your own question at least make the quetion clear and give a test case example with a code, etc

Comment: i know very well the :read-write ... but i didn't understand your question at all and the relation with it

Comment: What does "displaying only text" or "support only text display" mean? I have a feeling something was lost in translation here, because on the surface they seem to refer to almost any element.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can do this with a [`:read-write` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:read-write).

[Browser text case.](https://jsfiddle.net/CyberAP/k7nr6d8y/)

```
:-moz-read-write
{}

:read-write
{}

input[readonly],
input[type=date],
input[type=time],
textarea
{}
```

- `:read-write` will select any element that can accept text input;
- Can't use `:read-only`, due to poor support in Safari and Firefox. Instead, use a basic attribute selector. (`readonly` attribute is supported only on text-accepting inputs);
- We have to select `textarea` with a `:read-only` as well, but it's simpler to just write `textarea`;
- Firefox doesn't select `date` and `time` input types with `:read-write`, so we have to select them explicitly.